# XMLREADER gives different result when xml is indented

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have the same XML in two different files.
In one file the XML is indented - the other not.
The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
  <element1></element1>
  <element2></element2>
  <element3></element3>
</test>
```

When using the following code I get different result with the two files:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
   IgnoreComments = true,
   IgnoreWhitespace = false,
   IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true
};

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(invoiceStream, settings))
{
  reader.MoveToContent();
  reader.Read();
  var prevLocalname = reader.LocalName;
  var element = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
  var newLocalname = reader.LocalName;
}
```

With the indented file I get the following values:

```
prevLocalname = "";
newLocalname = "element1";
```

With the file not indented I get the following values:

```
prevLocalname = "element1";
newLocalname = "element2";
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Let us show your settings declkaration
there you can play with IgnoreWhitespace Indent and other properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - in the indented form, you've got a text node which you're getting the local name of (as empty). You're then moving to the next node, which is the `element1` element.

In the non-indented form, there's no text node, so you're getting the local name of `element1` to start with, and when you move to the next element it's reading `element2` instead.

If you tell the `XmlReader` to ignore irrelevant whitespace, the difference will go away - but you may lose cases where you *want* the whitespace to be considered relevant.

Comment: I have just updated the code example with the reader settings.

So if I change the IgnoreWhitespace to true, I should not see any differences?

Correct?

Comment: @JakobBrynitz: I'd *expect* that to be the case - but presumably it's easy for you to try it...

Comment: As a sidenote - why would I want whitespaces to be of importance in an XML document?

Comment: @JohSkeet: The change to igonre whitespace did give me the same result.

Comment: @JakobBrynitz: It depends on the document type. Sometimes you really *want* three spaces to be three spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the value below?

```
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
```

**[EDIT]**

Probably you would like to change the `settings`:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
   IgnoreComments = true,
   //IgnoreWhitespace = false,
   IgnoreWhitespace = true,
   IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true
};
```